# IntelliJ unable to recognize groovy String

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea, gradle

I am using IDEA - 11.1.1 and gradle - gradle-1.0-milestone-9 (I tried with release candidate 3 also) on windows-7 (if this matters)
After importing gradle porject, IDEA complains about String object. I think I am missing something about grrovy configuration. I have also marked - main and test folder as Sources and Test Resources respectively. Did I miss something obvious?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a jdk/gdk configured?

Comment: Could you elaborate more? I can see java and groovy using `java -v` and `groovy -v`

Comment: Irrelevant to Intellij; they need to be configured in the project's settings--I've only seen errors like that when java or groovy isn't configured correctly. Ymmv.

Comment: Works fine here. I am using the same IntelliJ version. Groovy is 1.8.0. In `build.gradle` I have the `groovy` plugin configured and in `dependencies` section I have `groovy "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:1.8.0"`. Btw, I have generated IntelliJ settings files with `gradle idea`, but I should work with gradle import in the same way, I presume.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most likely the JDK isn't set correctly in IDEA. Go to `File -> Project Structure -> Project` and check/fix `Project SDK`.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your project and module sdk.

On your module select F4 or Right click "Open Module Settings" 
Check your SDK and Moduel SDK

I am sure that will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check your IDEA project settings and look if your JDK is configured properly.

I suggest you use the `gradle idea plugin` to create your IDEA project files, instead of using the import function of existing gradle projects into IDEA, since from my experience it gave me troubles. Also adding new jars via gradle and updating your IDEA project files via gradle seems more consistent.

I uploaded a `build.gradle` gist, which might give you a good start: 
https://gist.github.com/1580234

It contains some explanatory comments.

Greets,

Jan